# How do I use the disks on an EC2 hi1.4xlarge spot instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'd like to try out EC2 and so I'd like to launch a cheap spot instance to play around with. The hi1.4xlarge is supposed to have 2 SSDs, but I can't find them on the machine. I've launched the instance with ami-58a3cf68 image, which is a 64-bit paravirtual Ubuntu 12.04 instance storage image.

During the setup phase, it says the disks will be /dev/sdb ad /dev/sdc.

[image]

However, when I log onto the machine, these disks don't appear to exist:

```
$ ls /dev/sdb
ls: cannot access /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/dev/xvdb` and `/dev/xvdc` instead.

Unfortunately there are a couple different "standards" for how to refer to device names in linux. Gotta love it, eh?